# Datatables : issue with append column data into select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

Hello everyone I'm trying to add several coloumn select filter into my datatables. I'm able to add select fields to each of the column but I'm unable to append the data from the table into the select fields as option, can anyone help me with this. any help is much appreciated.

Here are my code :

HTML :

```
<table id="project-content-datatable" class="display table table-hover table-responsive" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>ID</strong></th>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Preview</strong></th>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Parent</strong></th>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Name</strong></th>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Description</strong></th>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Category</strong></th>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Creation Time</strong></th>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Total Duration</strong></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript :

```
var content_table;
content_table = $('#project-content-datatable').dataTable({
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    JQueryUI: true,
    bPaginate: false,
    sScrollX: "100%",
    scrollY: '200vh',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    destroy: true,
    columnDefs: [
        {width: 1, targets: 0},
        {width: 1, targets: 1},
    ],
    responsive: false,
    select: true,
    buttons: getDataTableButtons(),
    ajax: {
        url: content_path,
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [
        {"data": "id", "class": "content_id id_padding-right ", "width": "5px"},
        {
            "data": "thumb",
            "class": "preview_padding-right ",
            "visible": false,
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return `<a href=` + data + ` data-fancybox> <img onerror="this.src='/media/dashboard/default/photo.png'" src=` + data + ` width="80" height="45"> </a>`;
            }
        },
        {"data": "parent", "visible": false},
        {"data": "name", "class": "content_name", "visible": true},
        {"data": "description", "class": "content_description", "visible": true},
        {
            "data": "category", "class": "", "visible": true, "render": function (data, type, row) {
            if (data != null) {
                return data.name;
            }
            else {
                return 'None';
            }
        }
        },
        {"data": "creation_time", "visible": false},
        {
            "data": null, "class": "content_duration ", "visible": true, "render": function (data, type, row) {

            // return get_duration(data);
            return 0;
        }
        }
    ]

});

$('#project-content-datatable').DataTable( {
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.header()) )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
});
```